Dense, everywhere dense, nowhere dense set definition
In Introductory Real Analysis by Kolmogorov and Fomin the following definitions are given:
Let A and B be two subsets of a metric space $R$. Then $A$ is said to be dense in $B$ if $B \subset [A]$. In particular, $A$ is said to be everywhere dense (in $R$) if $[A] = R$. A set $A$ is said to be nowhere dense if it is dense in no (open) sphere at all.
Here my question. If $A$ is dense in $B$, should not be $[A]=B$? Further, it is not clear to me the definition of nowhere dense.

If $A$ is a  subset of $B$ and the closure is taken in $B$, then you are right. But the authors don't assume that $A$ is a  subset of $B$ and they are taking closure in the bigger space $R$. Eg. $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $(0,1)$.

@geetha290krm: the authors don't assume that $A$
is a subset of $B$ --- Even if $A \subset B,$ we still might have $[A] \neq B.$ Let $R$ be the real numbers and let $A$ be the rational numbers and let $B$ be the algebraic numbers. (Paolo Secchi) For "nowhere dense", maybe this MSE answer will help.

@DaveL.Renfro Why not just $B=(0,1)$ and $B= A \cap \mathbb Q$ (in $R$).

@geetha290krm: Yes, that also works. It seems I included more layers of density than needed.

What is the notation $[A]$? Never seen it.

@Jakobian: I haven't seen this notation either, or at least I don't recall having seen it before. But it's clear from context that $[A]$ means the (topological) closure of $A.$

@DaveL.Renfro Yes. I checked the book and the notation is really there. What an odd choice by the authors.

@DaveL.Renfro Oddly enough, I see that in precisely one place, when talking about relative compactness, they did write $\overline{M}$. And in all other places they write $[M]$. It's really weird.
